# Wordpress list custom Taxonomy sub categories and Custom posts

Tags: wordpress

I cant seem to find a definitive answer to this question. I have a top level menu item called dairy which is made from custom posts within this there is further categories of cheese, milk, yogurt. Within the subcategories are the products.

When I click on dairy I want to list out a list of cheese, milk and yogurt categories - not the products within them. Is there a function that I can call to list the categories within my top level category?

Cheers
J

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Open up your custom taxonomy template file which may look like: taxonomy-{taxonomyname}.php and paste the following code where ever you want to display the list:
 $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
 if ($term->parent == 0) {   
 wp_list_categories('taxonomy=YOUR-TAXONOMY-NAME&depth=1&show_count=0
```

&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->term_id);
     } else {
    wp_list_categories('taxonomy=YOUR-TAXONOMY-NAME&show_count=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->parent); 
    }
    //reference 
    //http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-child-taxonomy-on-parent-taxonomys-archive-page/